# Store positive/negative sign in MySQL

Tags: mysql, types, enums, mariadb

I will be during a recursive query, and need to store the sign of some associated data.  How best to do so?

Maybe

- Make sign Boolean and use `IF(sign, 1, -1)`
- Make sign `tinyint` and limit sign values to +1 or -1.

If limiting values to +1 and -1, how best to do so?  Interestingly, integers apparently cannot be stored in a `enum` datatype (however, 1 and -1 can be strings)

[image]

My recursive query will be something like the following, however, `weight` will be changed to `sign` (reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258770/1032531).

```
WITH
    RECURSIVE t AS(
    SELECT
        pha.*,
        h.value
    FROM
        portfolios_has_accounts pha
    LEFT OUTER JOIN holdings h ON
        h.accounts_id = pha.accounts_id
    WHERE
        pha.portfolios_id = "p1"
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    pha.portfolios_id,
    pha.accounts_id,
    pha.weight * t.weight,
    h.value
FROM
    t
INNER JOIN portfolios_has_accounts pha ON
    pha.portfolios_id = t.accounts_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN holdings h ON
    h.accounts_id = pha.accounts_id
)
SELECT
    SUM(weight * value)
FROM
    t
WHERE
value IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more context here about the recursive part. Is this in a stored procedure? is there application code? Where does the "sign" come from?

Comment: @tadman  Added an example query.  User provides the sign and stores it in the database, and later it is used in another query.

Comment: Why aren't you just storing it as a signed `TINYINT`, or a `BOOLEAN` 1/0?

Comment: This isn't MySQL query, MySQL doesn't support WITH RECURSIVE ... AS... i removed the mysql tag please tag the correct database

Comment: @ceejayoz  I will be storing it either as `TINYINT`, `BOOLEAN`, or maybe the evil `ENUM`.  If `TINYINT`, guess I should just use a FK to enforce +/-1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I don't believe you are correct.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: @user1032531 https://www.google.nl/search?q=mysql+WITH+AS

Comment: @user1032531 Why not enforce +/-1 at the application level? Data validation isn't really SQL's cup of tea.

Comment: @ceejayoz why not most databases support CHECK constraint as data validation

Comment: @user1032531 "@RaymondNijland I don't believe you are correct. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html" MySQL 8 isn't out jet not a stabile version annyway...

Comment: @ceejayoz  I thought the DB should always be used ensure correct data when feasible.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  My question relates to storing signs and not recursive queries.